# Allowing my rooted Sanyo Zio to work with my Vista 64 computer

Tags: rooting, rom, usb-drivers

I recently got my Sanyo Zio phone and I would like to upload my android programs that i coded earlier onto it. I installed the driver that I found on the website and then plugged in my phone and when prompted I located the usb driver folder. Yet the installation failed. I tried the same thing with a new driver i found for vista x64. The same problem reoccurred. (i found multiple drivers for both vista x64 and x84 and tried installing all of them) None of them have worked. I can access my phones SD drive no problem but i would like to upload my software from eclipse.

Because of the response I got from costumer service (locted below) I decided that I will root my phone if it allows me to upload my programs from my computer. Does anybody know of a rom that will work with vista 64 on sanyo zio.?

Anyone has any ideas??

Update: I have send a msg to the costumer service for my phone the response is quite upsetting

---

> Dear XXXXXX,
>
> Thank you for contacting Kyocera Communications Inc. This email message is in response to your email about the difficulty of installing the Sanyo Zio device driver in a Windows Vista 64-bit PC and in a Windows Vista x86 PC.
>
> We are sorry to hear about the difficulties you are experiencing with your phone and appreciate the opportunity to assist you.
>
> Unfortunately the Sanyo Zio device driver will only work in your Window Vista x86 PC. If you are having difficulty installing the Sanyo Zio M6000 device driver in your PC, please try to download and install the Sanyo Zio SCP-8600 device driver.
>
> The Sanyo Zio will only work in your Windows Vista 64-bit PC if you set it as a mass storage device. To set it as a mass storage device, connect the USB data cable from your phone to your computer then from your Sanyo Zio just press "Mount".
>
> If you have any further questions, or are interested in purchasing, or information on accessories for your Kyocera Communications Inc. phone, please contact us at any of the phone numbers listed below:
>
> -E-Mail: phone-help@kyocera.com -Phone: (800) 349-4478 (Toll-free USA and Canada only) -Sanyo Accessories: (877) 204-1816 -Kyocera Accessories: KyoceraWeb@scp4me.com -International Access: (858) 882-1401 (Outside the USA) -Fax: (858) 882-1717
>
> Please help us improve our service by taking the survey. Click the link below:
>
> http://www.surveymonkey.com/s/VKK5RWC
>
> Thank you for contacting Kyocera Communications Inc. Ivan Technical Support Specialist
>
> Phone:
>   Zip:
>   Carrier: Cricket Wireless
>   Feedback:
>   I tried to install the usb driver on my vista x64 laptop. I then connect my phone and locate the driver but the installation fails. (i tried this with the driver for vista both the 64 and the x86 version)

---

Submitted via form: http://www.ziobykyocera.com/tech-support/

So any ideas on how to get my applications on my phone without installing the driver or how to install a driver anyways... Im kinda desperate :/

**Update** I have rooted my phone and I am willing to install a rom on it to make it connect with my computer. Will that help? If it would how would i go about doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately rooting your phone won't change a thing, as the problem is on the Windows side.  If Windows doesn't have a way to communicate with the phone (ie, a driver), then it doesn't matter if the phone has a different ROM on it - the hardware is still the same.

However, if you package your apps as APKs you can upload them to the SD card and then click on them to install that way.  In Eclipse: right click on the project > Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package.  Follow the prompts and you're flying.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer and the phone are on the same network, than you can use ADB via wifi.

There's an app that makes it to turn it on/off: [adbWireless](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=siir.es.adbWireless)

After enabling it open a command prompt and execute:

```
adb connect ip:5555
```

Comment: thanks but none of the adb wireless apps work on my android they all crash right away